# Does $\int_{\mathbb R} F(u(x)) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} F(u(-x)) dx$ hold also when $u$ is not even?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I got another question, similar to the one I just posted. I am reading some notes where it is assumed that $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a function of class $C^2$ and $u:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$. ($F$ is also assumed to be nonnegative, but I think it is not important for what I am asking).

In the notes it is written that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} F(u(x)) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} F(u(-x)) dx.$$

Now, if $u$ is even (but it is not the case), the result is correct. I am wondering if it is also true when $u$ is not even.

I am doing it this way:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} F(u(-x)) dx =\int_{-\infty}^0 F(u(-x)) dx +\int_0^{+\infty} F(u(-x)) dx = -\int_{+\infty}^0 F(u(x)) dx -\int_0^{-\infty} F(u(x)) dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 F(u(x)) dx +\int_0^{+\infty} F(u(x)) dx =\int_{\mathbb R} F(u(x)) dx,$$

which means that the result is true, as stated in the notes. However, it sounds a bit weird to me. Is that a sort of general property? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: This is invariance of Lebesgue measure under the transformation $x \to -x$. Note that $(a,b)$ and $(-b,-a)$ have the same length.

Comment: OP must be overthinking. Substitution $x'=-x$ immediately establishes the equality as pointed out by the above comment.

Comment: @geetha290krm, thanks. So, one can skip the proof (like the one I wrote) and just say the result is "trivial" and it can be justified mentioning only the invariance of the Lebesgue measure under the transformation $x\mapsto -x$?

Comment: Imho there is no overthinking. Your proof can be a little simplified. You do not have to split up the integral. Never stop going to the bottoms. According to Freddy Mercury they make the world go round.

Comment: @KurtG., thank you for your comment. Could you please tell me how to simplify the proof?

Comment: As I say, don't split the integrals. You can also consider just a function $f(x)\,:$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(-x)\,dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\, (-dx) \stackrel{(y\,:=-x)}{=} -\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} f(y)\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx\,.
$$

Comment: If $f\ge 0$ the integral  represents the area of the region between the line $y=0$ and the graph $y=f(x).$ If you apply the symmetry with respect to $x=0$ the area will not change.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.